# Fragment in Navigation Drawer not loading and makes the app crash. What can I do?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, drawer

So, I built a Navigation Drawer for my program with the following code:

This is the main xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HomeScreen">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/eb_bar"
            layout="@layout/eb_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/eb_bar"
            android:background="@color/frame_layout_bg"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.myapps.project.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the xml for the Navigation Drawer:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/navigation_drawer_background"
    tools:context="com.myapps.project.NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_frame_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/splash_screen_bg"
        android:elevation="3dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_logo"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_drawer_center_logo"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/navigation_drawer_center_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_menu_ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nav_drawer_frame_logo"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is xml of the fragment that I want to load:

```
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Second_screen"
    android:tag="Second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00F"
    tools:context="com.myapps.project.Second_Screen"
    android:name="com.myapps.project.Second_Screen"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second_screen">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_second_screen" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I also have two .java. One for the main screen and one for the Navigation Drawer. On the main screen I have this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


        toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.eb_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        TextView toolbar_home_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar_textview);
        toolbar_home_title.setText(R.string.home_screen_title);
        toolbar_home_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_txt_color));

        toolBar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_bg));

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_navigation_drawer);

        navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.frag_navigation_drawer,
                navDrawerLayout, toolBar);

        navDrawerMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items);

        navDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_menu_ListView);

        FragNavigationDrawer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_navigation_drawer);

        navDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_item,
                navDrawerMenuItems));

        navDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {

        String a = navDrawerMenuItems[position];

        Fragment navFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(a);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_screen, navFragment)
                .commit();

        navDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position,true);
        navDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(FragNavigationDrawer);
    }
```

The navDrawerMenuItems array has the names that are loaded into the Drawer to be the clickable items. They're also the tags of each fragment I want to load on the screen. So, what I'm trying to do inside the selectItem is to load the fragment by its tag, replace it on the main screen and close the drawer at the end.
But this code is showing the error:

```
2449-2449/com.myapps.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapps.project, PID: 2449
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:416)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:451)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:443)
        at com.myapps.project.MainScreen.selectItem(MainScreen.java:106)
        at com.myapps.project.MainScreen$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainScreen.java:88)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post complete logcat error trace?

Comment: Complete error message updated.

Comment: Can you point out line# 106 in `MainScreen.java`

Comment: Line 106 is the one that says: .replace(R.id.main_screen, navFragment)
Line 88 is: public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager** not **android.app.FragmentManager**.
Then try this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

**Update**

Can You check this?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_navigation_drawer">
```

The above line in xml is id for fragment. And you are casting it as frame layout in java file.

```
FragNavigationDrawer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_navigation_drawer);
```

Comment: Okay, I've made the change and the error is still there.
I did:

Fragment navFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(a);

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_screen, navFragment)
                .commit();

Comment: Thanks man! It worked now. I've let this part you pointed out of the code 'cause I don't know how to properly make it work. Anyway, the main operation I needed is right now.

Comment: So observation is important :)

Comment: It's strange 'cause android requires this field to be filled like this and in other parts of the code it works without problem, but on this piece exactly it makes the app crash. Anyway, thanks again.